# Use name_search in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want use name search but below example not working.

Tag 1   1234

Tag 2   2568

Tag 3   0369

After type 036 I want get Tag 3!

```
    class MyTags(models.Model):
        _name = "my.tags"
        _description = "Tags"

        name = fields.Char(required=True)
        color = fields.Integer(string='Color Index')


        @api.multi
        def name_get(self):
            result = []
            for record in self:
                name = '[' + str(record.color) + ']' + ' ' + record.name
                result.append((record.id, name))
            return result


@api.model
    def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
        args = args or []
        recs = self.browse()
        if name:
            recs = self.search([('color', '=', name)] + args, limit=limit)
        if not recs:
            recs = self.search([('name', operator, name)] + args, limit=limit)
        return recs.name_get()
```

Note

Above example work fine after type or scan exactly eg. 0369 return Tag 3, but after type eg. 036  not return.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `like` or `ilike` operator to get such searches to work. It has to be `[('color', 'ilike', name)]` then. If you want a more specific search pattern, you could also use `=like` or `=ilike`, but i have no example for them right now, so look into [Odoo doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#domains) to find out, what they are doing.

Edit: it's also helpful to get search wildcards around the search team:

`name` would be `'%' + name + '%'` so `[('name', 'ilike', '%036%')]` should find `0369` tag.